# How to clearly view the object type?

Tags: object, visual-studio-code, types, pycharm, read-eval-print-loop

I'm quite a beginner in Python and have been using PyCharm for some weeks.

I'm trying VS Code at the moment and when I'm putting code into the REPL, I wonder if there's a way to display the different objects type ? ... like Pycharm can do in a side frame ;-)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can always return it with the type function.

```
type(object)
```